# Installation and initial startup with mariadb in docker container in unraid

Tags: mariadb

I'm hoping someone can help me.  I'm very new with server-side stuff, so if you find yourself thinking, "This guy doesn't know what he's doing," you're right, I don't. :)

I have a brand-new installation of UnRaid, with nothing on it other than installing the disks and creating a few shares.  My first task has been to install MariaDB to use Nextcloud.  Under the apps tab in UnRaid, I configured and installed the MariaDB container from linuxserver's repository.  When MariaDB starts, though, I get the following log, which keeps appending the same lines to itself ad infinitum.

```
[migrations] started
[migrations] no migrations found
usermod: no changes
───────────────────────────────────────

      ██╗     ███████╗██╗ ██████╗ 
      ██║     ██╔════╝██║██╔═══██╗
      ██║     ███████╗██║██║   ██║
      ██║     ╚════██║██║██║   ██║
      ███████╗███████║██║╚██████╔╝
      ╚══════╝╚══════╝╚═╝ ╚═════╝ 

   Brought to you by linuxserver.io
───────────────────────────────────────

To support LSIO projects visit:
https://www.linuxserver.io/donate/

───────────────────────────────────────
GID/UID
───────────────────────────────────────

User UID:    99
User GID:    100
───────────────────────────────────────

[custom-init] No custom files found, skipping...
UMASK corrected from 022 to 0640 ...
231104 16:10:29 mysqld_safe Logging to '/config/databases/a8e981b155d7.err'.
231104 16:10:29 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /config/databases
[ls.io-init] done.
Caught SIGTERM signal!
UMASK corrected from 022 to 0640 ...
231104 16:10:32 mysqld_safe Logging to '/config/databases/a8e981b155d7.err'.
231104 16:10:32 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /config/databases
Caught SIGTERM signal!
cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: No such file or directory
UMASK must be a 3-digit mode with an additional leading 0 to indicate octal.
The first digit will be corrected to 6, the others may be 0, 2, 4, or 6.
UMASK corrected from 022 to 0640 ...
231104 16:10:36 mysqld_safe Logging to '/config/databases/a8e981b155d7.err'.
231104 16:10:36 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /config/databases
Caught SIGTERM signal!
cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: No such file or directory
UMASK must be a 3-digit mode with an additional leading 0 to indicate octal.
The first digit will be corrected to 6, the others may be 0, 2, 4, or 6.
UMASK corrected from 022 to 0640 ...
231104 16:10:40 mysqld_safe Logging to '/config/databases/a8e981b155d7.err'.
231104 16:10:40 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /config/databases
Caught SIGTERM signal!
cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: No such file or directory
UMASK must be a 3-digit mode with an additional leading 0 to indicate octal.
The first digit will be corrected to 6, the others may be 0, 2, 4, or 6.
UMASK corrected from 022 to 0640 ...
231104 16:10:43 mysqld_safe Logging to '/config/databases/a8e981b155d7.err'.
231104 16:10:43 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /config/databases
Caught SIGTERM signal!
cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: No such file or directory
UMASK must be a 3-digit mode with an additional leading 0 to indicate octal.
The first digit will be corrected to 6, the others may be 0, 2, 4, or 6.
UMASK corrected from 022 to 0640 ...
231104 16:10:47 mysqld_safe Logging to '/config/databases/a8e981b155d7.err'.
231104 16:10:47 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /config/databases
Caught SIGTERM signal!
cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: No such file or directory
UMASK must be a 3-digit mode with an additional leading 0 to indicate octal.
The first digit will be corrected to 6, the others may be 0, 2, 4, or 6.
UMASK corrected from 022 to 0640 ...
231104 16:10:50 mysqld_safe Logging to '/config/databases/a8e981b155d7.err'.
231104 16:10:50 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /config/databases
```

Also, here are the first few lines of the referenced **/config/databases/a8e981b155d7.err** file, which is also a continuous repeat of the following lines:

```
2023-11-04 16:26:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 231104 16:26:58
2023-11-04 16:26:58 1 [Warning] Failed to load slave replication state from table mysql.gtid_slave_pos: 1146: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist
2023-11-04 16:27:00 0 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
2023-11-04 16:27:00 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2023-11-04 16:27:00 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2023-11-04 16:27:00 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
2023-11-04 16:27:00 0 [ERROR] Aborting
231104 16:27:02 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
231104 16:27:02 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /config/databases
2023-11-04 16:27:02 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.11.5-MariaDB-log source revision 7875294b6b74b53dd3aaa723e6cc103d2bb47b2c as process 18618
2023-11-04 16:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.13
2023-11-04 16:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
2023-11-04 16:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2023-11-04 16:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2023-11-04 16:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 256.000MiB, chunk size = 4.000MiB
2023-11-04 16:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-11-04 16:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffered log writes (block size=512 bytes)
2023-11-04 16:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: End of log at LSN=36893
2023-11-04 16:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-11-04 16:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-11-04 16:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
2023-11-04 16:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 36893; transaction id 4
2023-11-04 16:27:02 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-11-04 16:27:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /config/databases/ib_buffer_pool
2023-11-04 16:27:02 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table: "Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist". Some plugins may be not loaded
```

As you can see, it gets into a repeating loop.  I'm unable to run mariadb-check without getting connection errors, so I assume the database is never completely starting.

As everything is so fresh and new, I can't imagine that it's conflicting with anything else (and besides, it's in a Docker container).

I've literally spent 7 hours Googling and experimenting with solutions, but I'm crying "Uncle" and asking for help at this point.

Any guidance anyone would be able to lend would be most appreciated.

Brent

Comment: [Mostly solved](https://www.reddit.com/r/mariadb/comments/17nxrye/install_of_maria_db_on_brandnew_unraid_system/) per other report.